# How to select records with a count >30?

Tags: mysql, select, count, distinct

So I have this data set (down below) and I'm simply trying to gather all data based on records in field 1 that have a count of more than 30 (meaning a distinct brand that has 30+ record entries) that's it lol!

I've been trying a lot of different distinct, count esc type of queries but I'm falling short. Any help is appreciated :)

[Data Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4TTF.png)

Comment: Look into GROUP BY ;) https://www.w3resource.com/sql/aggregate-functions/count-having.php

Comment: please show (as text, not an image) example results that you are trying to get

Comment: what does `select version();` show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using GROUP BY and HAVING you can achieve this. To select more columns remember to add them to the GROUP BY clause as well.

```
SELECT Mens_Brand FROM your_table
WHERE Mens_Brand IN (SELECT Mens_Brand
FROM your_table 
GROUP BY Mens_Brand 
HAVING COUNT(Mens_Brand)>=30)
```

Comment: The syntax makes sense, but im getting this error.                                                      Error Code: 1055. Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'mens_shoes.shoe_data.Mens_Price' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: @PabloCuellar the 'group by' means you will only get one row returned for each distinct Mens_Brand; you can't do that *and* return all the columns, since some columns will presumably differ for database rows with the same mens brand.

Comment: @ysth makes sense thank you. Thats what I'm trying to figure out. Is there a workaround like doing a (DELETE FROM table_name WHERE brand NOT LIKE '', '', '',)  Because I know the brands that do fit into the criteria so if I just delete the ones that are not like those it will eliminate all records right? I'm new to SQL so it its sounds good in my head but not sure if its operationally possible in SQL Thanks!

Comment: Updated my answer, wrote it a bit too hasty. Add columns at will as long as it's contained in the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: I understand that now, but when I do a COUNT aggregate, it wont show me the individual records of each brand I'm trying to get. Itll just give me a count of how many records instead of just giving me the brands that have at least 30 records. Does that make sense? I want all the data but just want to eliminate brands that don't have 30 records, while being able to see all the records individually

Comment: Got it ;) Was 3 am when i wrote this. Check updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm just learning querying so this was very helpful! :) @EgilHansen

Comment: @EgilHansen One more question if you have time! If I want to delete all other records would this be the proper query?

Comment: `delete from mens_shoes.shoe_data
where mens_brand IN (
SELECT * 
FROM mens_shoes.shoe_data
WHERE Mens_Brand IN
(SELECT Mens_Brand
FROM mens_shoes.shoe_data
GROUP BY Mens_Brand 
HAVING COUNT(Mens_Brand)<30)
); `      @EgilHansen

Comment: @EgilHansen I seem to get error 1241

Comment: To delete all records based on having a count < 30: 
DELETE FROM your_table
WHERE Mens_Brand IN (SELECT Mens_Brand
FROM your_table 
GROUP BY Mens_Brand 
HAVING COUNT(Mens_Brand)<30)

Comment: @PabloCuellar there are two different ways to do what you want, depending on what version you have.  but you aren't responding to comments on your question

Comment: @EgilHansen I get error 1093 because I can’t reference the table within the sub query. What would you do in this case?

Comment: @ysth sorry it’s V 8.0.29

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a window function (requires mysql 8 or mariadb 10.2) for this:

```
select Mens_Brand, Mens_Price, Shoe_Condition, Currency, PK
from (
    select Mens_Brand, Mens_Price, Shoe_Condition, Currency, PK, count(1) over (partition by Mens_Brand) brand_count
    from your_table
) counted where brand_count >= 30
```